# Optimal scanned resolution for final printing at 1 x 2,5 m

Tags: scanning

We have a piece of artwork (~21 x 30 cm) originally scanned at 300 dpi

Should we rescan it at another resolution if it is going to be printed on a poster of 1 x 2,5 m ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: At what distance should it be recognizable (optionally, for text only, *readable*)? 300 dpi is plenty for books and magazines, and these are read at half a meter away, tops.

Comment: @jongware Thanks for responding. It's mostly artwork, although there's a bit of text. But I don't think people are going to look at it from very close. Is there a rule of thumb for the optimum ratio viewing distance: dpi ?  Thanks in advance

Comment: I found this to help with the viewing distance question. (http://www.premierpress.com/2013/05/resolution-recommendations/) I'm not affiliated with this company however it could help you deside if you need to rescan the image. From what I calculated your image would be around 31 ppi. According to the site that I am using for reference this would be ok for a viewing distance of 25 Feet.

Comment: @Art of Fitz.  Thanks a lot for your reply. People will almost certainly be looking at the image from closer than 25 feet. Two more questions, if you don't mind: (I know the first question is very naive, but better safe than sorry) As a general rule, the larger the size of the displayed image, the smaller dpi that is required ? For an image of 1 x 2.5 m is 300 dpi almost definitely overkill ? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: This is difficult to answer a general "Yes". Some files if built correctly could be printed at a lower ppi. However, the file would need to start at the final dimensions in order to proceed. Due to your original question. Your file is at a small dimensional size. So increasing this file you are limited in how large it can increase. So maybe the rule you're looking for is "Start Big go Small." Overkill no, I know a print company that can print 10 feet by ?? long at 1,000 ppi. It depends on how  much clarity you want in the final print.

Comment: @Art of FITZ Thanks again. What I meant by 'overkill' is that I could most probably reduce the resolution (ie make it less than 300 ppi) without worrying about any pixelation. Correct ? Thanks

Comment: Looking back at your original question. It looks like you are wanting to scan your image in order to print the image at a larger size. I would suggest scanning your image at 300 dpi or higher and then you can reduce the file for print to around 150 ppi. You have a greater risk of "pixelation", we should call it artifacts, occurring on a lower scan. Once again "Start Big go Small".

Answer (score 0):

I dug a little deeper I really want to provide you with the most accurate answer. The Scan should be at 12000 x 29700 pixels. How did I come up with this number... Well I'll provide the math really simply and then if you really want to delve deep follow this link to [All About Digital Photography.](http://www.rideau-info.com/photos/scanning.html)
Take your final dimentions `1m x 2.5m`
and the printer output of `300 ppi`
I then convert your `Meters` to `Inches`
1m = `39.3701`
2.5m = `98.4252`
Then you calculate the pixel dimentions
`40in * 300ppi = 12000` (I rounded up the inches)
`99in * 300ppi = 29700` (I rounded up the inches)
The scan should be at 12000 x 29700 pixels for a resolution of 300 ppi.
I know this is a few days after our original comments. However, I knew that I needed to find some resources that could help me backup my math and explanation. Hope this helps.

Comment: But note that rarely would you need to print a 2.5m poster at 300dpi. A large-format printer would likely be running at 100dpi for most uses.